# lazy load inside multithread.pool.imap() occure multiple times instead one

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, lazy-loading

Let's assume a have class

```
class Helper(object):
 @property  
 def lazy_prop(self):
   if not self.__model:
      self.__model = init()
 return self.__model
...
```

and I have function

```
def action(data):
 #handle some  actions which using Helper
```

and I have some data, which need to be handled with `action` function like this

```
data = ['bla-bla', 'foo-foo']
pool = Pool()
pool.imap(action, data)
```

**The problems is that lazy property goes to be initialized many times, instead of single one**. Why that happens and how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

With `multiprocessing`, if you spawn multiple jobs then the `Helper.lazy_prop` will be initialized in each `Process`.